# Strange behaviour of \iftoggle inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, etoolbox

I want to set flag from inside of decoration which I want to check outside of the decoration. I set the flag (call `\toggletrue{}` or `\togglefalse{}`) but when I check this flag it always false.

For MWE I define a new decoration that do nothing except set the flag. Apply this decoration to the circle. And then check the flag.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{toggletest}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{custom decoration}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[
    width=+0pt,
    next state=final,
    persistent precomputation={%
      \toggletrue{toggletest}
    }
  ]{}

  \state{final}{}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [
  postaction={%
    decorate,
    decoration={%
      custom decoration
    }
  }
] (0,0) circle (2cm);

\iftoggle{toggletest}{%
  \draw [green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
}{%
  \draw [red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It should draw green circle if `toggletest` is true and red one otherwise. But it draw always red one.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a global setting:

```
\pgfdeclaredecoration{custom decoration}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[
    width=+0pt,
    next state=final,
    persistent precomputation={%
      \global\toggletrue{toggletest}
    }
  ]{}

  \state{final}{}
}
```

However, a simple `\newif` would be enough here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\newif\iftoggletest \toggletestfalse

\pgfdeclaredecoration{custom decoration}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[
    width=+0pt,
    next state=final,
    persistent precomputation={%
      \global\toggletesttrue
    }
  ]{}
  \state{final}{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [
  postaction={%
    decorate,
    decoration={%
      custom decoration
    }
  }
] (0,0) circle (2cm);

\iftoggletest
  \draw [green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\else
  \draw [red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fi

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the use of `\newif` would be problematic when the file is `\input` into another document using the facilities of `standalone`? I can only get it to work if I comment the lines concerning the `if` in the preamble of the input file. (Obviously I define `\newif` etc. in the calling document.) I thought that `standalone` would skip the entire preamble but for some reason `\newif\ifmine\minefalse` causes errors if it is still present in the preamble.